# Force VS to ask user where to save new file when it was opened from within current instance

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm working on a Visual Studio package kind of project where I have several features and functions, including a custom editor, similar to the one exposed in here: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/03/12/LearnVSXNowPart15.aspx

One of the things I'm doing once editor factory and its file extension is registered is provide the user with a Menu item to create a new file with my own type of extension (lets call it ".myext"), and I do so by using this code:

```
  var tempFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.GetTempFileName());
  var tempDir = tempFileInfo.Directory.ToString + @"\";
  var fullFileName = tempDir + "NewFile1.myext";

  try
  {
    using (var fs = File.Create(fullFileName))
    {
      var info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("");
      fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
...
```

After the file was created, I need to OPEN it WITHIN the SAME Visual Studio INSTANCE I'm running in now (to make use of the editor I previously created and registered to my extension), so I do this:

```
...         
    var applicationObject = GetDTE2();
    applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", fullFileName);
```

And I finally dispose of the file since I no longer need it.

```
      File.Delete(fullFileName);
```

The problem comes when the user wants to save the file because, even though the file at "fullFileName" no longer exists, if the [image: save button] button is clicked it would re-create/save the file at the temp location it was originally created, never asking the user to choose a path for this new file.

Is there something I can do now to force Visual Studio to always ask the user where to save the file instead of letting it use the "default" save?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a lot of thinking around this problem, I've came to the conclusion I was creating the file using a wrong way. I ended up changing that part of my code for:

```
if (Instance == null) return;

  try
  {
    string scriptExtension = ".myext";
    var itemOp = Instance.GetDTE2().ItemOperations;
    const string fileNameBase = "NewFile1";
    itemOp.NewFile(@"General\Text File", fileNameBase + scriptExtension, "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred. " + ex.Message);
  }
```

The file always opens in the registered editor for the corresponding extension, and it seems it doesn't matter you create it based on the template of a textfile as long as you set the file extension in the file name.

Using this way to create the file since it is never saved to a physical location, when the user clicks the Save button Visual Studio will ask him where to save the file.